# The proper way to manage a Google Drive account using Java console application?

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I have enabled Google Drive API on Google Developer Console and created a service account credential which is bundled with a `service account ID` and `key ID`. Despite that I have tried various ways to manage **my own Google Drive account**, I could not find a solution which fits for my aim. I need to **upload**, **download** and **delete** the files stored in my own Google Drive. The application that I am going to connect Google Drive is a **console one** which will be solely used for an academic research.

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty simple. The steps to achieve this are at [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic)

Be careful about how securely the refresh token is being stored and what scopes you grant to the app.